# How to get rid of jerky movement in scrolling? C# / XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, scrolling

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code meant to create a scrolling background of random-ish ones and zeros. When moving to the right (or left), it scrolls smoothly for a few seconds, stops/jerks, then starts scrolling smoothly again. I've spent an entire day now trying to iron out this issue and nothing that I've done makes it any better.

Here is my isolated code:

```
    namespace TestScrollyNumbers
    {
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }

    KeyboardState CKBS = new KeyboardState();

    Random Randomness = new Random();

    Texture2D NumberScrolly1;
    Texture2D NumberScrolly2;
    Texture2D NumberScrolly3;
    Texture2D NumberScrolly4;
    Texture2D NumberScrolly5;

    float XPosScroll = 0;
    float XPosScrollVel = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int meh = 1;

    public List<Texture2D> BackgroundScrollyTextures = new List<Texture2D>();

    public List<float> ScrollyNumberXPos = new List<float>(); //This list contains the final X positions for the number bars.
    public List<float> ScrollyNumberXStart = new List<float>(); //This will be used to calculate the final X positions for each bar.

    public List<int> ScrollyNumberMultiplier = new List<int>(); //List of Y position multipliers so that I can calculate the Ypos in the draw command.
    public List<int> ScrollyNumberType = new List<int>(); //List of randomized textures for each bar.

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        BackgroundScrollyTextures.Add(NumberScrolly1);
        BackgroundScrollyTextures.Add(NumberScrolly2);
        BackgroundScrollyTextures.Add(NumberScrolly3);
        BackgroundScrollyTextures.Add(NumberScrolly4);
        BackgroundScrollyTextures.Add(NumberScrolly5); //Add all of the possible textures to the list of textures so that each number in the "ScrollyNumberType" list can correspond to a texture. 
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        NumberScrolly1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("NumbersForBackground1");
        NumberScrolly2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("NumbersForBackground1");
        NumberScrolly3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("NumbersForBackground1");
        NumberScrolly4 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("NumbersForBackground1");
        NumberScrolly5 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("NumbersForBackground1"); //Loading :P
    }
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        CKBS = Keyboard.GetState(); //Current Key Board State

        if (meh == 1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 18; i++)
            {
                ScrollyNumberMultiplier.Add(Randomness.Next(0, 11));
                ScrollyNumberType.Add(Randomness.Next(0, 5));
                ScrollyNumberXStart.Add(i * 80); //Each bar is 80 pixels wide
                ScrollyNumberXPos.Add(0);
            }
            meh = 0;
        }

        if (CKBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            XPosScrollVel += .6f;
        }
        if (CKBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            XPosScrollVel -= .6f;
        } //Scrolling - add to the velocity

        XPosScrollVel *= .9f;
        XPosScroll += XPosScrollVel; //Add the current X Velocity to the X Scroll

        for (i = 0; i < ScrollyNumberType.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ScrollyNumberXPos[i] < -79)
            {
                ScrollyNumberXStart[i] += 1440; //Instead of creating a new bar, use the bar that just went off of the screen and give it a new Y pos value
                ScrollyNumberMultiplier[i] = Randomness.Next(0, 11);
            }
            if (ScrollyNumberXPos[i] > 1365)
            {
                ScrollyNumberXStart[i] -= 1440; //Same thing as before, except reverse.
                ScrollyNumberMultiplier[i] = Randomness.Next(0, 11);
            }
            ScrollyNumberXPos[i] = ScrollyNumberXStart[i] - XPosScroll; //final XPos = where it started, plus how many times it's gone across the screen, minus how much you've scrolled.
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        for (i = 0; i < ScrollyNumberType.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(BackgroundScrollyTextures[ScrollyNumberType[i]], new Vector2((int)ScrollyNumberXPos[i], (-37 - 56 * ScrollyNumberMultiplier[i])), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        } //And then draw everything.

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

You can use this image to test my code (I didn't include the four others as that would make this post unnecessarily long) if you don't know the answer right away:

[image]

For anyone wondering, I use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and XNA Game Studio 4.0.

Comment: Try `graphics.IsFullScreen = true;` otherwise the issue is most likely due to the GPU being shared.

Comment: Hmm no, that didn't work. Same behavior. As for my computer lagging, I thought I already ruled that out with an inconclusive time test, but I guess I'll try again...? I don't think it'll make much of a difference though.

Comment: Okay I closed everything else down except for my project and it still has the same glitchy movement. Surely there's nothing special with my game and I'm not the only person who has laggy movement. Is there a fix for this? What I'm doing shouldn't be hard for my computer (or any computer for that matter) to handle...

Comment: Did you try multiply your movement by gametime? Otherwise profile it by checking how long the functions for drawing this image takes. If there is no difference in time then the FPS drop should be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: My guess is the freezes come fron the garbage cycles. I think you can check that using the performance monitor tool (perfmon).

Comment: @MennoGouw I tried multiplying by (gametime.elapsedgametime.milliseconds / 16.6666) and (gametime.elapsedgametime.totalmilliseconds / 16.6666) in several places but nothing worked. Also, when I drew the 18 textures using a smaller, 34 pixels wide, 36 pixels high texture in my test project which I pasted above, I experienced the same glitchyness. Why would there even be a FPS drop in my test program? I'm not doing anything intensive... ):

Comment: @Felsir Okay I'm not really sure how to use perfmon at all, and I've never dealt with the garbage collector. Is there something about my code that would make the garbage collector take a long time or something?

Comment: The code looks fine. The only thing I can think of is the part: `new Vector2((int)ScrollyNumberXPos[i], (-37 - 56 * ScrollyNumberMultiplier[i]))` in the draw call. I think this allocates a new space to do the calculation; try creating a variable outside the for loop, and set its' X and Y value in the loop? See also this blogpost for more information on garbage collection issues affecting performance: http://steveproxna.blogspot.nl/2010/02/remote-performance-monitor.html

Comment: Really you should try logging the time things take. Just a stopwatch before a function and after a function. First you profile the whole draw method then half, if that half does not change the other half. Try to find exactly where the program takes long to load.

Comment: I tried this:             for (i = 0; i < ScrollyNumberType.Count; i++)
            {
                current.X = (int)ScrollyNumberXPos[i];
                current.Y = YposYay[i];
                spriteBatch.Draw(BackgroundScrollyTextures[ScrollyNumberType[i]], current, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, oneone, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
            } but no luck. current is a vector2 and YposYay is set where the Xposition is set with the calculation.

Comment: @Felsir Xbox usually is the one with problems for garbage collection, but a PC can handle *tons* of garbage collection without any problem. A few Vector2s being created (and thrown away) every frame is not going to make a difference.

Comment: EDIT: however, I just realized it could be possible that the garbage collector is disposing of excessive offscreen pixels.

Comment: Might be it? Though I think that is a gpu task? Test it by adding a source rectangle I guess. Still profiling seems sensible just to confirm/rule out the GC.

Comment: @Felsir I'm not sure if offscreen pixels are garbage collected or not but the GPU does require memory to hold information about pixels so I suppose they might be in some way.

Comment: @Superdoggy and Felsir It still lags when all pixels are on the screen (using the tiny 34 by 36 texture, preventing it from going offscreen a single pixel) and when I'm using the optimized vector2 stuff that you suggested, Felsir. I'm wondering now if it has to do with my way of structuring programs...? Any known problems with using lists for everything?

Comment: In my experience this behaviour usually is a GC round. Try running perfmon (start it via the start-run command perfmon) add the counters attached to the process and see what happens. Also, is the behaviour also present in a release build or just in a debug build?

Comment: @Felsir I started to go through the tutorial that you linked, but I don't have an XBOX 360. Just a PC. Is there a way that I can still use this tool?

Comment: Yes, run it from your windows commandline perfmon. You should be able to add counters. There should be a bunch of .Net counters there. Expand the one related to memory (not neat a PC now, don't recall the exact name) there should be a counter measuring GC calls. If a spike in the graph matches the framerate drop, it is probably a GC issue.

Comment: @Felsir Okay, I figured out how to run it but I don't know how to read it... too many things are red and I don't know what I'm looking at.

Comment: @Felsir - appears not to be directly a GC issue - see my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a possible solution. Set `this.IsFixedTimeStep` to false.

What this does is syncs Update to Draw so that the game gets updated only as the screen can be drawn. That means that if the game were to lag the game physics (if done in update) would go slower, but it's probably worth it if this graphical glitch is annoying you.

I found another post on the issue so it appears that it is not new. http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/75475/459289.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That worked and got rid of about 90-95% of the movement glitches in my program.

Comment: You need to modify your code to make it time dependant because without the fixed timestep your code is depending on the speed of the machine running it. Even so, in a fixed timestep there is no guarantee you'll get 60 updates per second so including timing is always a sound practise.

Comment: @Felsir well yes if the game is dependent on a fixed speed then yes. But it seems the original post did not want choppy animations, and fixing the timestep / allowing skipped frames for time dependency appears not to be the goal here, but rather smooth animations. Also some games are more fun to play slowly rather than more laggy. ;)

Comment: I have to disagree here. If the game uses a fixed timestep, XNA *tries* to give you 60 frames per second. It may not always be the case, thus timing is still the best way to go. If you set the `IsFixedTimestep=false`, the game just calls update and draws as fast as the code allows (either limited by performance of the code *or* to the vsync of the monitor- which can be disabled by setting `SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false`). Either way, you have no guarantee the update is called in exactly the same frequency on all hardware. I do agree that laggy games are not fun to play though!

Comment: @Scratchifier  I am not convinced that unfixing the timestep fixes the issue- it just changes the timing (hence "got rid 90-95% of the glitches" this is probably because the Update() method is called less often because it now runs in sync with the Draw() method). Have you tried a release build and run the EXE? It might be due to garbage collection and the debugger requiring to update it's internals?

Comment: @Felsir I am not concerned about having exactly 60 updates per second. And my computer isn't what you'd call fast anymore (although it works pretty well, it's definitely not considered a "gaming PC") so it wouldn't slow down on many other PCs anyway. Lastly, this is more of a personal project than a marketable game. So, it might not be "industry standard" but it works for me.